# about debian iSCSI target setup

Tags: iscsi, multipath-storage

I'm trying to setup TGT-iSCSI on a debian vm (for testing), but when I try to connect from iscsi-client (xenserver, multipath enabled), I can only see 1 IP instead of the 2 IPs prepared for storage (that xenserver as well as the debian VM have 3 NICs, 1 for management, 2 for storage) ... when config xenserver storage for iSCSI I can only see 1 ip (if connecting to freenas I can see 2 IPs instead), when selecting between IQN:* or IQN:specific IP.. I believe I have to do something on at the debian VM side to specify which IPs I wanna "publish" just like freenas allows me to do.

Answer (score 0):

Tgtadm keeps a record of its portal addresses:

```
tgtadm --lld iscsi --op show --mode portal
```

You should be able to add a portal matching your secondary address:

```
tgtadm --lld iscsi --op new --mode portal --param portal=1.2.3.4:3260
```

From initiator, re-do the discovery, your LUNs should be visible on both addresses